# How can I depend on a sub-project of the buildSrc project in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project inside buildSrc/.

I would like to use one of these sub-projects as a dependency of a "normal" (not build-related) project.

To make things clearer, the project layout is more or less like this:

```
buildSrc/
    p1/
    p2/

main/
    main1/
    main2/
build.gradle
```

Now, what I want is to make `:main:main1`, for example, depend on `buildSrc/p1`.

I have been able to achieve this by including `buildSrc/p1` in both `/settings.gradle` and in `buildSrc/settings.gradle`, but that's not very good (it's basically duplicating the project in 2 separate project trees) and causes IntelliJ, for example, to fail to import the project properly (which is my main issue, actually).

Is there a good way to solve this problem without moving `buildSrc/p1` to a separate Gradle project or repository (it's important that we keep being able to evolve the code in both projects together with minimal friction)?

Comment: Check out the spring guide, maybe it helps event your project is not spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: I don't think you can do that without, like you mention, moving p1 to a stand-alone project. I am actually surprised that you could get it to work (except for IntelliJ) with a normal include in the first place.

Comment: Filed a bug with JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34585